# Why does alert() return undefined after entering inconsistent number of digits?

Tags: javascript, undefined, alert

```
function seclar(){
    var x=123456789, largest, secondlargest;

    largest=parseInt(prompt("Enter a number", ""));

    while(x != 0){
        x=parseInt(prompt("Enter a number", ""));

        if(x>=largest){
            secondlargest=largest;
            largest=x;
        }

        else if(x>=secondlargest && x!=largest){
            secondlargest=x;

        }
    }
    alert("Second largest is " + secondlargest);
}
```

alert returns undefined when numbers of varying numbers of digits is entered. please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you entered an `x` that is less than previously entered `largest`, then your code will try to do following comparison:

```
x >= secondlargest && x != largest
```

While at the time `secondlargest` hasn't been assigned any value, it's `undefined`. So the comparison `x >= secondlargest` would be `false`.

So, when you finally come to the `alert` statement, `secondlargest` is still not assigned any value.